# VBA Excel Workbook with Database connection to SQL server need login information

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have an Excel VBA workbook that I have created. It has a control panel page with a button installed to run the VB/ASP script that runs against our SQL Database. I have created text boxes for entry for dates and have used these as input for the VB/ASP script that pulls the individual sheets(Reports). Now, I want to declare the username from ENVIRON ("UserName") then evaluate the username against a list of usernames and return the user_id (aka UserNumber) to the text box on the control panel page (user_id in sql database).
Example: if sjones is logged into windows then evaluate list of Usernames=165?, then 
Var1 = Var1 & "OR ( pd.created_by = '" + Sheets("Control Panel").UserNumber.Text + "' ) ) " & vbCrLf

I want to pull reports based on the person logged into Windows at the time to keep others from running the report for anyone but themselves.  The worksheet location is open to all users but I want them to only run the reports for the user logged in? There is probably an easier way to do this but I am very weak in VB/ASP. Please help. TIA Conya

Comment: Where are you having problems? Post the relevant parts of your code and someone might be able to help.

Comment: Are you really using ASP? If you are using ASP, how are you communicating with the ASP server?

Answer (score 0):

Get username first and execute a sql query to get a userID associated with that. The code might looks like:

```
Public UName, UID as String 

Public Sub GetUName()
    UName = Environ("USERNAME") 
End Sub

Public Sub GetUID()
    strSQL = "Select UID from table1 where username=" & "'" UName & "'"
    UID = oConn.Execute strSQL
End Sub
```